# Regex to find quotes closest to certain characters

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm trying to match quotes for a surrounding timestamps with an E9 at the end:

`"(?=-?\d*\.?\d+E[+-]?\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/bG1tQ9/2

I have the first half of the regex where it's matching the quote before the E9 but I can't seem to get the other quote.

The language is javascript and it's going to be used to string.replace on a stringified json.

Comment: did you want to match only the quotes? lookarounds are assertions which won't consume any single chars.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't decode the JSON first, make the changes and then write it out again?

Comment: I can't set a property of the json to be 12345678E9 without it being a string in js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"(-?\d*\.?\d+E[+-]?\d+)"
```

You can use this and replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/bG1tQ9/4

Comment: Or if it should ONLY match E9 at the end (not E8 etc), use this: "(-?\d*\.?\d+E9)"

Answer (score 1):

Am I correct in thinking you want to remove the double-quotes from around the timestamp? If so then this does the job:

```
var s = '"23452345235E9", "0342953475409E9", 324598732450843, "fooo", "2034598324509E9", 12342340985, "baaar", 234098549034E9, 453409340923';

var re = new RegExp(/"(\d+E9)"/g);

s = s.replace(re, '$1');
```

see [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/garyh/7zaw9eyw/)